# How to stop a specific docker container using Python

Tags: python, docker

I have a Docker compose file that starts a database, webserver, and a worker. Our users may need to run additional workers and I have that working (using "...up --scale worker=x"). The user may also want to stop a specific worker. This is where I run into trouble. On the command line, I can use "docker stop worker_name" and that works okay but not when I'm calling it from Python using subprocess. I've seen reference to using docker-compose stop but doesn't docker-compose go by your yml file? How could you use it to stop a single container? We're using Python 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. Docker version is 18.06.

Here's a snippet from Python for stopping the worker.

```
kwargs - { 'shell': True,
   'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
   'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
   'universal_newlines': True
   }
worker_name = 'worker_1'
cmd = f'docker stop {worker_name}'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
out, err = proc.communicate()
self.logger.info(f'out = {out}')
self.logger.info(f'err = {err}')
```

Comment: Why not share your python code? There is no reason `bash command` works, but `python subprocess` call this command not work.

Comment: @atline see my additions.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

When you use `docker stop` in a command line, does the container stop at once or is there a significant delay?(*) If the latter, in the container, is the worker started by a script without using `exec`? If this is the case, the SIGTERM/SIGINT is sent to the container main process, which is the script, and which cannot do anything with it since the control is in the core worker code.

To be correct, the starter script should `exec` the core worker code, so that the worker becomes the container's main process (or more accurately, that the container's main process becomes the worker code). The SIGINT/SIGTERM will be processed by that process and the container will stop in a timely manner.

(*) when you do a `docker stop` the container is sent a SIGINT (or is that a SIGTERM); and if it doesn't terminate in a timely fashion (10 seconds IIRC) then it is given the axe with a SIGKILL.

Comment: It takes about 5-8 seconds to stop. Our workers are running celery, so the worker.docker file uses the following: CMD celery worker --app=myapp --loglevel=info --concurrency=1 -Q myplugin -n myplugin-$HOSTNAME. I don't think we are using exec.

Comment: Looks like [code is properly exec'ed](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/docker/entrypoint), unfortunately.